# MYSQL replay dumpfile all or nothing in a transaction

Tags: shell, mysql

MYSQL re dump from a log.sql all or nothing

```
mysql -h "$databaseHost" -u "$username" --password="$password" "$databaseName" <                      /path/to/project/log.sql
```

if this log.sql file contains an error in middle then transaction before error are done and after error are not done..

BUT i want that either whole of the sql file show be re dump OR nothing from the file should be re-dumped
i am using MySQL database and Debian(6.0.1) O.S

log.sql

```
  start transaction;
  insert into demo_table values('abc');
  insert just for to create an error;
  insert into demo_table values('xyz');
  commit;
```

shell script for it:

```
rollBack () {
      if [ $mysql_error -eq 1 ]; then    
      mysql -h "$databaseHost" -u "$username" --password="$password" "$databaseName" -e "rollback;";
      exit 0;
      fi  

 }

 mysql -h "$databaseHost" -u "$username" --password="$password" "$databaseName" < /path/to/project/log.sql|| if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then mysql_error=1; rollBack; fi
```

i tried this code its not working any help or suggestions please friends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: Following is only tested roughly, there might be more things to consider when dumping, depending on your database.*

That's only possible under certain circumstances.

First failure is, that a transaction is bound to a session. Since you connect again to issue the `rollback`, the `rollback` has no use since there's no transaction to rollback. That was in the other session.

Second failure is, that usually a mysqldump has several statements which cast an implicit `commit` and therefore end the transaction. This includes all DDL statements (data definition language, this includes `drop`, `alter`, `create` and so on) as well as `(un)lock tables`.
So, to execute your dumpfile in one single transaction, the dump should have been created something like this:

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppw database --no-create-info --skip-add-locks --skip-disable-keys --skip-triggers >dumpfiles
```

`--no-create-info` lets mysqldump skip all `drop table ...; create table ...;` statements.

`--skip-add-locks` lets mysqldump skip all `lock table ...; unlock table ...;` statements.

`--skip-disable-keys` lets mysqldump skip all `alter table ... disable keys; alter table ...enable keys;` statements.

`--skip-triggers` lets mysqldump skip all `create trigger ...;` statements.

There's also a `--single-transaction` option, but this option would only be applied to single tables.

Third (possible) failure is, that a transaction only can be rollbacked completely, if all tables involved are capable of transactions, like InnoDB or BDB. If you have i.e. MyISAM tables in there, the `insert` statements will not get rolled back.

The following fails, cause the `source` command is not allowed in a stored procedure, it's rather part of the mysql client.

<s>If all that has been considered, you can do it like this:</s>

First create a procedure like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_exec_dumpfile()
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN 
  ROLLBACK;
END ;

START TRANSACTION;

SOURCE '/path/to/dumpfile.sql';

COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then execute it like this in your script:

```
mysql -uuser -ppw -hhost databasename -e "CALL sp_exec_dump()"
```

Or of course you parameterize the procedure with the dumpfile name.

Comment: i tried the stored procedure its give me syntax error near declare
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 

in the line

Comment: Have you issed the `DELIMITER $$` statement?

Comment: @user310685 Corrected it. Please have a try again.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/path/to/dumpfile.sql;  COMMIT; END' at line 13

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm afraid it seems like the `source` command is not allowed in stored procedures.

Comment: A colleague of me just mentioned this: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys as a possible alternative.

Comment: sorry for late replay i will surely try it using a function

Comment: i tried it doing a function but this time it gives an error at ROLLBACK; i think rollback dosent go with function .. still i post a new Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979664/mysql-dump-statement-within-a-stored-procedure-amazon-aws may be i get it

Comment: I didn't explain it well. The syntax error results from not knowing the `source` command. The `source` command is a feature of the mysql command line client. It does not work in a stored procedure. And there's a difference between a stored procedure and a function. You used a stored procedure in your new question and it will not work in a function. You can have a try with the link I provided 2 comments above.

Comment: sorry sir i am getting nothing from that link it is very difficult for me to get it.. is there any easy alternative for it