# MYSQL redump from a log.sql all or nothing

Tags: mysql, shell

MYSQL re dump from a log.sql all or nothing

```
mysql -h "$databaseHost" -u "$username" --password="$password" "$databaseName" < /path/to/project/log.sql
```

if this log.sql file contains an error in middle then transaction before error are done and after error are not done..

BUT i want that either whole of the sql file show be re dump OR nothing from the file should be re-dumped i am using MySQL database and Debian(6.0.1) O.S

log.sql

```
start transaction;
insert into demo_table values('abc');
insert just for to create an error;
insert into demo_table values('xyz');
commit;
```

shell script for it:

```
rollBack () {
 if [ $mysql_error -eq 1 ]; then    
 mysql -h "$databaseHost" -u "$username" --password="$password" "$databaseName" -e    "rollback;";
 exit 0;
 fi  

 }

  mysql -h "$databaseHost" -u "$username" --password="$password" "$databaseName" < /path/to/project/log.sql|| if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then mysql_error=1; rollBack; fi
```

i tried this code its not working any help or suggestions please friends

stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_exec_dumpfile(
        IN in_file VARCHAR(1024)
 )
BEGIN

 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
 BEGIN 
  ROLLBACK;
 END ;

  START TRANSACTION;

   SOURCE in_file;

   COMMIT;
   END $$
   DELIMITER ;
```

ERROR: SYTANX ERROR NEAR SOURCE 'in'

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementation issues. It is not suitable for migration since it has already been cross-posted to Stack Overflow. In the future, do not cross-post questions. If a question is off-topic on one site and is of sufficient quality, moderators can migrate it to an appropriate site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL replay dumpfile all or nothing in a transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909215/mysql-replay-dumpfile-all-or-nothing-in-a-transaction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problem are you experiencing? If you find that the rollback command does not work, then you should check your table type - last time I checked, MyISAM tables do not support transactions and you had to use [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) tables.

If the volume of data is small enough, you could:

- Use `mysqldump` to dump out database so that you have a "before" copy. Ensure you include table definitions and "DROP IF EXISTS" statements.
- Attempt to load "log.sql"
- If an error occurs, load the "before" copy to put everything back the way it was. That assumes the dump doesn't run into a problem either.

Comment: thanku for the answer .. simply i just want to write a stroed procedure to mysql rollback.. i have updated the Question with stored procedure code ..